# How to get the decomposition of T^2 hotelling in mult.chart as a matrix in output?

Tags: r, msqc

I run mult.chart package for T^2 hotelling . I want to get just "the first point" that is out of control and "it's decomposition" as a matrix.But running these codes get all out of control points and all decomposition in the type of "list". and i can't separate the first point and it's decomposition and save them. what should i do?

```
    a<- runif(400,0,1)
    b<- matrix(a, nrow=100,ncol=4)
    output <- mult.chart(type="t2", alpha=0.07,b)
```

I expect the output for example number 70 (out of control point) and the decomposition matrix of that with 15 row and 7 columns (titles: t2 decomp, ucl , p-value ,1 ,2 ,3, 4), but the actual output is a list with all out of control points and the decomposition of those as a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you saw, is only printed when your type is t2 and is not stored in output. You can see in [the code](https://github.com/cran/MSQC/blob/master/R/mult.chart.R) the table is variable q, and not returned.

I basically took the calculation part out (nasty bit of code) and wrote it into a function:

```
printOutlier = function(x,output,alpha){
p <- ncol(x)
m <- nrow(x)
x <- array(data.matrix(x), c(m, p, 1))
n <- dim(x)[3]
phase <- 2
x.jk <- matrix(0, m, p)
t2=output$t2
x.jk <- apply(x, 1:2, mean)
Xmv <- output$Xmv
S <- output$covariance
colm <- nrow(x)
ucl = output$ucl

t3 <- which(t2 > ucl)
res = vector("list",length(t3))
for (ii in 1:length(t3)) {
       v = 1
       k = 0
       for (i in 1:p) {
              k <- k + factorial(p)/(factorial(i) * factorial(p -i))
                }
       q <- matrix(0, k, p + 3)
       for (i in 1:p) {
                  a <- t(combn(p, i))
                  for (l in 1:nrow(a)) {
                    for (j in 1:ncol(a)) {
                      q[v, j + 3] <- a[l, j]
                    }
                    v = v + 1
                  }
                }
       for (i in 1:nrow(q)) {
              b <- subset(q[i, 4:ncol(q)], q[i, 4:ncol(q)] > 0)
              di <- length(b)
              if (length(b) > 1) {
              q[i, 1] <- n * t(Xmv[b] - x.jk[t3[ii], ][b]) %*% 
              solve(S[b, b]) %*% (Xmv[b] - x.jk[t3[ii],][b])
                  }
              else (q[i, 1] <- n * (x.jk[t3[ii], ][b] - Xmv[b])^2/S[b, b])
              ifelse(n == 1, ifelse(phase == 1, q[i, 2] <- ((colm - 
                    1)^2)/colm * qbeta(1 - alpha, di/2, (((2 * 
                    (colm - 1)^2)/(3 * colm - 4) - di - 1)/2)), 
                    q[i, 2] <- ((di * (colm + 1) * (colm - 1))/((colm^2) - 
                      colm * di)) * qf(1 - alpha, di, colm - 
                      di)), ifelse(phase == 1, q[i, 2] <- (di * 
                    (colm - 1) * (n - 1))/(colm * n - colm - 
                    di + 1) * qf(1 - alpha, di, colm * n - colm - 
                    di + 1), q[i, 2] <- (di * (colm + 1) * (n - 
                    1))/(colm * n - colm - di + 1) * qf(1 - alpha, 
                    di, colm * n - colm - di + 1)))
                  q[i, 3] <- 1 - pf(q[i, 1], di, colm - 1)
                }
                colnames(q) <- c("t2 decomp", "ucl", "p-value", 1:p)
                names(res)[ii] <- paste(`Decomposition of` = t3[ii])
                res[[ii]] <- round(q, 4)
            }
       return(res)
}
```

Now if you run your mult.chart again, and use this function, it should give you the table:

```
library(MSQC)
set.seed(111)
a<- runif(400,0,1)
b<- matrix(a, nrow=100,ncol=4)
output <- mult.chart(type="t2", alpha=0.07,b)

printOutlier(b,output,0.07)
```